# Java sort ArrayList with custom fields by number and alphabetically

Tags: java, sorting

```
public class Product implements Serializable{

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price ;
    private int quantity;

    public Product(String id, String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price + ", quantity=" + quantity + '}';
    }
```

I want to sort `ArrayList<Product>` by price and name. I search Google for a long time but I cann't solve it. Whether it can have problem with **Serializable**

Comment: price first, then name?

Comment: How did you try to sort the `List`?

Comment: 1 case with name, 1 case with price. Not both

Comment: I dont rememember. Some of them are using Collections in class, some implements Comparable

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to implement `Comparable` or `Comparator` interface for your purpose. [sorting user defined objects with Comparator](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/) and [sorting user defined objects with comparable](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-1/)

You can learn the difference between these two by reading these tutorials

Consider you want your products to be sorted using its price then make your `Product` implement `Comparable` as follows

```
public class Product implements Comparable<Product>{

    public int compareTo(Product other){
       // your logic here
    }

}
```

But hold on... now that we have already implemented `Comparable` interface to sort the objects using its price, how can we sort them using another sort sequence? We only have one `compareTo()` method and we can't write separate sort sequence in the same class. Here comes the role of `Comparator`. With `Comparator`, you can define multiple sort sequences.

Suppose we want to sort using its price, then:

```
public class PriceSorter implements Comparator<Product>{

    public int compare(Product one, Product another){
        int returnVal = 0;

    if(one.getPrice() < another.getPrice()){
        returnVal =  -1;
    }else if(one.getPrice() > another.getPrice()){
        returnVal =  1;
    }else if(one.getPrice() == another.getPrice()){
        returnVal =  0;
    }
    return returnVal;
    }
}
```

and you want another sort sequence, now for its name, then:

```
public class NameSorter implements Comparator<Product>{

        public int compare(Product one, Product another){
            return one.getName().compareTo(another.getName());
        }
}
```

Now, when you want to sort using price, then

```
Collections.sort(yourList,new PriceSorter());
```

If you want to sort using name, then

```
Collections.sort(yourList, new NameSorter());
```

The second argument takes the `Comparator` instance which makes the sort method know what logic to follow while sorting objects

Comment: You mean `Comparable`

Comment: @morgano, both can solve the purpose. `Comparator` has certain advantages over `Comparable`

Comment: In this specific case what it must be impletented is `Comparable`. You implement `Comparator` if your object is going to compare between objects, not if your object is going to be compared.

Comment: @morgano, It is not possible if user is not allowed to change the code for `Product` class. Using `Comparator` , he doesn't have to change anything in `Product` class. Well you can use anonymous class for that. But if we want to create multiple sort sequences, then Comparator is a must.

Comment: One question and I may be off here, but the primitive `double` does not have a `compareTo` method.  Since `getPrice` returns the primitive, is some autoboxing occuring that allows the use of `compareTo`?

Comment: I try Pricesorter. But it show warning: **double cannot dereferenced**

Comment: This could have been because of the problem @KevinBowersox pointed out. I've edited the answer accordingly. It works

Comment: The first part of your code is wrong. I don't see **one**. So it can't be **one.getPrice()**

Comment: @haind, I'm sorry I misplaced the code. I should have put it in PriceSort. I've edited accordingly

Comment: @Kharkar Yeah! Thank for your help.It's very nice.Now, it works for me

Comment: wow, this solve my issue, very fast and neat, thanks for this.

Answer (score 5):

Have the `Product` class implement the `Comparable` interface.

```
public class Product implements Serializable, Comparable<Product> {

        //Ommitted constructors, fields and accessors

    //This is an ascending sort order
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        int result = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.name);
        if(result != 0){
            return result;
        }else{
            return new Double(this.price).compareTo(new Double(o.price));
        }   
    }
}
```

Then sorting is as easy as pass the `List` to `Collections.sort()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product p1 = new Product("p1", "shoes", 30.33, 20);
    Product p2 = new Product("p2", "shoes", 20.30, 20);
    Product p3 = new Product("p3", "shoes", 50.33, 20);
    Product p4 = new Product("p4", "socks", 10.50, 20);
    Product p5 = new Product("p5", "socks", 5.40, 20);
    Product p6 = new Product("p6", "socks", 2.34, 20);

    List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6);

    System.out.println("Unsorted");
    for(Product product:products){
        System.out.println("Product: " + product.name + " Price: " + product.price);
    }

    Collections.sort(products);

    System.out.println("sorted");
    for(Product product:products){
        System.out.println("Product: " + product.name + " Price: " + product.price);
    }
}
```

**Here is the full source** for `Product` that implements `Comparable` with a sort example in the `main` method:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Product implements Serializable, Comparable<Product> {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Product(String id, String name, double price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product{" + "id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", price=" + price
                + ", quantity=" + quantity + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Product o) {
        int result = this.name.compareToIgnoreCase(o.name);
        if(result != 0){
            return result;
        }else{
            return new Double(this.price).compareTo(new Double(o.price));
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product p1 = new Product("p1", "shoes", 30.33, 20);
        Product p2 = new Product("p2", "shoes", 20.30, 20);
        Product p3 = new Product("p3", "shoes", 50.33, 20);
        Product p4 = new Product("p4", "socks", 10.50, 20);
        Product p5 = new Product("p5", "socks", 5.40, 20);
        Product p6 = new Product("p6", "socks", 2.34, 20);

        List<Product> products = Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6);

        System.out.println("Unsorted");
        for(Product product:products){
            System.out.println("Product: " + product.name + " Price: " + product.price);
        }

        Collections.sort(products);

        System.out.println("sorted");
        for(Product product:products){
            System.out.println("Product: " + product.name + " Price: " + product.price);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @haind Did you receive an error message?  Or was the sort not as you expected?  If so how did you expect the sort to function?

Comment: Here is result: 20.3 30.33 50.33 2.34 5.4 10.5

Comment: @haind That was how I interpreted that you wanted the functionality.  It first sorts by the product name then it sorts by the price, both in ascending order.  I assume that result should have contained the product name?

Comment: That's not what I mean. I want to sort by price and name for each case. Now I know why it is 20.3 30.33 50.33 2.34 5.4 10.5

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Comparator<Product>`, here implemented anonymously (suitable for java 7 and earlier):

```
List<Product> list;
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Product>() {
    public int compare(Product a, Product b) {
        if (a.getPrice() == b.getPrice())
            return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName()); 
        return a.getPrice() > b.getPrice() ? 1 : a.getPrice() < b.getPrice() ? -1 : 0
    }
});
```

Java 8 has a much cleaner way of achieving the above:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(Product::getPrice).thenComparing(Product::getName));
```

If this defines the "natural order" of your products, consider making `Product` implement `Comparable<Product>` and implement it in the `compareTo()` method of `Product`.

Comment: Earlier worked for me. No need to see update but for 8 it seems good

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `Comparable` interface. The interface requires you to add a function called `compareTo(Product other)` within which you write the code that checks the custom fields you want the objects to be compared by.

Alternatively you can do what @Prasad Kharkar suggested and write a `Comaparator` that essentially does the same thing.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , you dont have such methods , what you can do is ; extend a subclass of Collection and add methods to sort (search or techniques like bubble sort,and more)

If you have facility for a database (more overhead)
*you could put it in there and use order by
*if you are using JPA , just dump your list into a entity class